# Express $|\pi - \frac{23}{7}|$ without the absolute value symbol

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> Express $\left|\pi - \dfrac{23}{7}\right|$ without the absolute value symbol.

I know I have to check if $\pi - \dfrac{23}{7}$ is greater than (or equal to) zero, but how can I do it analytically (without a calculator)?

I know that $\pi \gt 3=\dfrac{21}{7}$ but how to compare $\pi$ with $\dfrac{23}{7}$?

Comment: What facts about $\pi$ do you know, or are allowed to use, in answering this question? Because if you know that the first few digits of its decimal expansion are $3.14$, it's pretty easy.

Comment: Hint: $2/7 > 2/8 = 0.25$.  This is all you need, assuming you know that $\pi \approx 3.14$.

Comment: If an explanation is not required in your answer (e.g. the question is "answer only" or "multiple choice"), then it follows from the (essentially) "common knowledge fact" that $22/7$ is the best approximation for $\pi$ using one- and two-digit integers that $\pi$ has to be between $21/7$ and $23/7.$ (Why best? Common sense -- if another such approximation was better, then everyone would be learning the other approximation and not the $22/7$ approximation.)

Comment: $\int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{(1+x^2)} = \frac{22}{7} - \pi$ is the integral of a positive function, hence a positive quantity. Therefore $\frac {22}7 > \pi$.  The same follows for $\frac {23}7$. I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, it is "analytically" showing what you need.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619010/how-is-the-upper-bound-on-archimedes-approximation-of-pi-justified) for a proof of the perimeter bound using the theory of sequences.

Comment: Um.... I don't see how you can actually solve this without knowing significant information about the value of $\pi$.   I was taught that $\frac {22}7$ is a very good estimation of $\pi$ which implies $\frac {22}7$ is a better estimation than $\frac {21}7$ or $\frac {23}7$.  So If $\frac {22}7$ is a better estimate and $\frac {23}7$ is a worst estimate than $\frac {23}7$ is too big and $\pi -\frac {23}7 < 0$ so $|\pi -\frac {23}7| =\frac {23}7-\pi$.... but I was also taught that $\pi \approx 3.14$ so.... to be continued....

Comment: $\frac {23}7 = 3\frac 27$ and we have to compare $\frac 27$ to $0.14$ but $7\times 0.14 < 1 < 2$ so $\frac 27<0.14$ and $\frac {23}7 > 3.14\approx \pi$.  But *all* of those assume I know something about the value of $\pi$. so..... I don't understand your question.  If you don't know *anything* about the size of $\pi$ you can't answer this.  If you *do* know something about the size of $\pi$ then you probably know $\pi < \frac {23}7$ and there isn't anything *to* answer.

Comment: Meh..... I suppose this is probably good enough for pre-calculus.   $3.14 < \pi < 3.15$ so $3.14\times 7 =21.98 < 7\pi < 3.15\times 7 = 22.05$ so $21 < 21.98 < 7\pi < 22.05 < 23$ so $\frac {21}7 < \pi < \frac {23}7$.  ... [This also shows us that $21.98 < 7\pi < 22.05$ so $7\pi \approx 22$ and therefore $\pi \approx \frac {22}7$ is a very good estimation.  (unfortunately this is not enough to tell us if $\frac {22}7$ is bigger or less than $\pi$..... Of course if we just do $3.141 < \pi < 3.142$ we can probably figure that out.)

Answer (score 25):

I will not use any approximations in this answer.

Consider the definite integral $$\int_0^1\frac{t^4(1-t)^4}{1+t^2}dt.$$ Simply expand the numerator using binomial formula and reduce the numerator in terms of the denominator. I’ll skip a few steps for the sake of brevity: $$\int_0^1\frac{t^4(1-t)^4}{1+t^2}dt=\int_0^1\left(-4t^5+t^6+t^4+\frac{4t^6}{1+t^2} \right)dt$$$$= \int_0^1\left(-4t^5+t^6+5t^4-\frac{4t^4}{1+t^2} \right)dt= \int_0^1\left(-4t^5+t^6+5t^4-4t^2+\frac{4t^2}{1+t^2} \right)dt $$$$=  \int_0^1\left(-4t^5+t^6+5t^4-4t^2+4-\frac{4}{1+t^2} \right)dt$$$$=\bbox[5px, border:2px solid red]{\frac{22}{7}-\pi.}$$ This is a very nice expression containing both $\dfrac{22}{7}$ and $\pi$.

Now, note that the function $\displaystyle f(t)= \frac{t^4(1-t)^4}{1+t^2}$ is ALWAYS positive for all $t\in (0,1)$. This means that the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{t^4(1-t)^4}{1+t^2} dt$ is also strictly positive. Thus, we get, $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid gold]{\frac{22}{7}-\pi>0\implies \frac{22}{7}>\pi.}$$

Hence we finally arrive at the desired conclusion: $$\pi<\frac{22}{7}<\frac{23}{7}.$$

---

Thus, we can write $\Bigg |\pi-\dfrac{23}{7}\Bigg|=\dfrac{23}{7}-\pi$.

Comment: My mind? Blown.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC! Actually where I am from, “Prove that $\int_0^1\frac{t^4(1-t)^4}{1+t^2}dt=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$” is a very popular question in worksheets. So all I had to do was to connect the OP’s question to the integral and write the last paragraph  by myself.

Comment: Not to detract from @insipidintegrator's fine solution (which I upvoted), but it can also be found elsewhere on Math.SE. It is a clever approach to the approximation, and a clearly non-Archimedean one.

Comment: Where does this integral come from? One of the series expansions for $\pi$? It seems too simple to have been conjured from scratch just for an exercise?

Comment: @EricSnyder I found this on mathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67384/source-and-context-of-frac227-pi-int-01-x-x24-dx-1x2

Comment: I’ll also add https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229847/asymptotic-quality-of-rational-approximations-to-pi, https://vixra.org/pdf/1711.0310v1.pdf, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662540/interpretation-of-frac227-pi, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048678/who-was-dalzell-pi-22-7 @EricSnyder

Answer (score 8):

Here's an idea that, like insipidintegrator's answer, avoids an approximation. Use a circumscribing polygon to upper-bound the circumference of the circle. I use a dodecagon, whose perimeter is

$$
P = 24 \tan \frac{\pi}{12} = 24(2-\sqrt3)
$$

[image]

We want to show that this $P < 2\left(\frac{23}{7}\right) = \frac{46}{7}$.

\begin{align}
24(2-\sqrt3) < \frac{46}{7}
    & \Leftrightarrow 84(2-\sqrt{3}) < 23 \\
    & \Leftrightarrow 168-84\sqrt{3} < 23 \\
    & \Leftrightarrow 145 < 84\sqrt{3} \\
    & \Leftrightarrow 21025 < 21168
\end{align}

Then, since $2\pi < P$, we have $\pi < \frac{23}{7}$. It should be pointed out that this does require you to accept that a circumscribing polygon is longer in perimeter than the circumference of the circle.

Answer (score 5):

You have already said that $\frac{21}{7}$ is 3, and that both $\pi$ and $\frac{23}{7}$ are greater than 3. But, $\frac{23}{7}$ would be $3\frac{2}{7}$, and we know that the first digit of $\frac{2}{7}$ after the decimal point is 2 (because 20 divided by 7 is 2.something). So, since $\pi$ starts with 3.1, it must be less than $\frac{23}{7}$, and thus the expression in question must be less than 0.

Answer (score 3):

It has been known for more than 22 centuries that $\pi<22/7$ (Archimedes). But if you don't know it, you can do primary school division:

\begin{array}{cccc|l}
2&3&0&0&\underline{7~~~~} \\ 
 &2&0& &328 \\
 & &6&0& \\
 & & &4
\end{array}

Thus we deduce that $23/7>3.28$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$\pi - \dfrac{23}{7} <\frac{315}{100}-\dfrac{23}{7}=\frac{2205}{700}-\dfrac{2300}{700}<0$$