# Can't find the answer for this integral can anyone help me?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I solve this integral?

$$\int_0^1 \frac {x^4 (1-x)^4}{x^2+1} dx$$

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80#Details_of_evaluation_of_the_integral) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Comment: And in general, look into integration by partial fractions---it's the go-to method to integrate rational functions (and is *especially* useful when the denominator's factorization into linear and quadratic polynomials is "easy").

Comment: If you want some more insight into the workings of this integral, you may look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496755/express-pi-dfrac237-without-the-absolute-value-symbol/4496777#4496777) (which is admittedly mine) and make sure to see some links I’ve posted in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would notice that this a "rational" function and that the numerator has higher degree than the denominator so we can divide to get a polynomial plus a rational function with denominator of higher degree than the numerator.

If I have done the algebra correctly
$\frac{x^4(1- x)^4}{x^2+ 1}= x^6- 4x^5+ 5x^4- 4x^2+ 4+ \frac{-3}{x^2+ 1}$

It should be easy to integrate that.

Comment: ow i didn't think of that thank you